# Probability of number of rows of seats occupied across identical set of busses

Tags: probability

We are given a few independent variables, 'n', 'b' and 'r' where:

- n: # of passengers waiting to board any bus
- b: # of busses
- r: # of rows of seats in each bus

Before we state the problem, let us make following assumptions:

- All busses are identical and go to the same destination so that each passenger is equally likely to choose any row in any bus
- Number of passengers (n) is less than or equal to the number of seats in each row

There are number of ways 'n' passengers can seat themselves across 'r' number of rows and across 'b' busses. Let 'k' denotes the maximum of the number of rows across all busses. For example, one seating arrangement could be (for n=4, r=16, b=8):

- Bus0: Row 0 is occupied with one passenger
- Bus1: Row 0 and 1 are occupied with one passenger each
- Bus2: Row 0 is occupied with one passenger
- Bus3 - Bus7: all rows are empty

In this example, 'k' is 2 because Bus1 has the maximum number of rows (=2) occupied.

I am interested in figuring out the probability (p_k) for all seating arrangements corresponding to all values of 'k' (k = 1, 2, ..., r). For example:

- p_1 => probability that, across any bus, exactly 1 row is occupied (by any number of passengers)
- p_2 => probability that, across any bus, exactly 2 rows are occupied (by any number of passengers) and so on ...

I am interested in understanding the series of steps involved in deriving a general form of expression for p_k which gives the probability of a seating arrangement for any value of 'k'.

Sum of all probabilities (p_k) must add to 1 (because 'k' takes finite set of values from 1, 2, ...,  r).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What assumptions are you making about how people choose to sit? If this is a real-world problem, it's reasonable that someone might avoid a row because it's already occupied by someone else.

Comment: When problems are stated this abstractly, it is essential that they be formulated absolutely clearly and fully, with no ambiguity or room for (mis)interpretation.  An alternative strategy (that often works better) is to explain the problem you *really* have, in its context, because that enables us to fill in some of the gaps with reasonable suggestions and assumptions.

Comment: I tried added a few more details. Please let me know if further clarification is needed.